# Is the conception of Daenerys Targaryen at the end of rebellion just a coincidence?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, fan-theory

Daenerys was born nine months after her mother's flight from King's Landing at the end of Robert's rebellion.

> She had been born on Dragonstone nine moons after their flight, while a raging summer storm threatened to rip the island fastness apart.

That means she was conceived around the time of sack of King's Landing. For a defeated, mad old man awaiting imminent death and a woman in immense stress, this would be an unusual time to conceive a new child. Besides, many misfortunes could have befallen the fleeing Queen Rhaella during her flight to Dragonstone that might lead to a miscarriage.

Is it possible we are looking at another case of pretended parentage like Jon Snow's, or is Daenerys's unusual conception at the conclusion of rebellion just a coincidence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty sure she was conceived without much forethought.

> All the executions by fire aroused the king and, while he and his wife had slept in separate chambers for some years and avoided each other by day as well, Aerys would always claim his marriage rights after such an execution by fire, brutally abusing his wife in bed.
>   <sub>*A Feast for Crows*, Chapter 16</sub>

Now the timing is uncertain, but we know that after things started going poorly for the Royalists, Aerys started hiding caches of wildfire around KL to burn it down, and we also know that when he found out Rhaegar fell, he sent his Queen to Dragonstone.  We also know that when his Hand Lord Chelsead found out about the wildfire, he confronted the King and was burned alive for it.  *A Dance with Dragons* epilogue.

While we don’t know the precise timing of things, it seems to me that Aerys burned his Hand, got aroused and knocked up his wife, then sent her on to Dragonstone.